# How to get dynamic initial route using go_router package?

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate user to a specific route based on whether is user logged in or not. I'm Using [go_router package](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for navigation.

```
MaterialApp.router(
        restorationScopeId: 'app',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routerConfig: router,          
      ),
```

I can't place home: or initialRoute parameter when using MaterialApp.router.

So how do I navigate to a specific route on launch?

Comment: Which platform? Is the app for web where there's url navigation? Does the not logged in user need to redirected on every page or specific pages? Can you post minimal example code of the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check the status and then redirect the user to your specefic page.

Something like that :

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter.of(context);

// Check the user's login status.
final bool isLoggedIn = await authenticationService.isLoggedIn();

// Navigate to the appropriate route based on the user's login status.
if (isLoggedIn) {
  router.go("/home");
} else {
  router.go("/login");
}
```